# Outlook PropertyFrom MAPI Schema Property ID

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I am looking to get the actual property name from a MAPI schema property. I'm obtaining the MAPI Schema property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x67AA000B" but I would like to know what field this corresponds to (I.E. Anniversary, BusinessAddress, etc). Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link to MSDN provides a table which shows the allocation of particular tag range values to an assigned purpose [MAPI Property Tag Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527392(EXCHG.10).aspx).

The table indicates that 0x67aa000b is in the following range:

```
0x6600  0x67FF  Provider-defined internal non-transmittable property
```

The value 0x000b indicates this is a Boolean type.

I presume the provider in this case is Exchange Server? Unfortunately I've been unable to locate a description of this property tag's meaning.