# Is there a list of IDs for the Outlook MAPI namespace?

Tags: vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin, mapi

I'm working on an Outlook add-in and I'm looking for a complete list that relates that MAPI properties to there names that is a little less vague than [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842410.aspx).

There is plenty of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms875203(EXCHG.65).aspx) [on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147567.aspx) [how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176395.aspx) to access those properties, but I'm not having much luck finding anything that tells me what any of the properties are.

P.S.  I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184427/outlook-propertyfrom-mapi-schema-property-id) on the subject but I would really like more info on the subject.

Alternatively, if there is information on extending the Out of Office Assistant, the would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some very rare cases there exists documentation from MS as you've seen.
The Exchange Server SDK gives you at least some symbolic names, [Outlook Spy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) knows some more by name, [OpenMAPI](http://git.openmapi.org/nmapi/tree/NMapi/Flags/Properties/properties.xml) has some named, some float around in the net.

As far as i know though, there is no definitive complete list.

*edit:*
If you were looking for the mapi properties of properties from the OOM though, Outlook Spy should name most of these. It has a 30 day test period and quickly becomes invaluable when working with Outlook.
And no, i'm not getting provisions ;)

Answer (score 16):

Fully documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433490(EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: oh yea! this is what we're looking for

Comment: these are exchange, not MAPI, I think - looking for one that includes `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` / `0x39fe001e`, and those don't seem to... any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that comes across this post and is using the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/` of accessing MAPI properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526356(v=exchg.10).aspx

Comment: My comment comes late, but this is literally a document from 08/21/2009 and for exchange-10...

Comment: Great! Worked for me. Not sure why this upset you so much that you have to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

For Outlook MAPI property IDs there is a list on slipstick: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/