# livelink mapi outlook objId

Tags: vba, mapi, outlook-2003, livelink

I am searching for a way to get the livelink objId from a MAPIFolder object (Outlook VBA).

I can get the path but its useless when the MAPI comes from favorites.

I look at this [Is there a list of IDs for the Outlook MAPI namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589483/is-there-a-list-of-ids-for-the-outlook-mapi-namespace) but that's not really helping.

I searched in each variable of MAPIFolder, looked at xml values, and I don't know what to do, where else to look.

(Are there any livelink/Outlook developers?)

Comment: What is Livelink and what is its relationship to Outlook and the VBA object model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any direct experience with automating LiveLink's Outlook Integration, but if their solution is MAPI Message Store Based (like our competing DMS integration product), your best bet would be to install [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) and look for a named property containing the livelink ID.

There doesn't have to be one, but it is the most straightforward approach to support third party automation/integration.