# Retrieving OutlookID of a Livelink folder

Tags: vba, outlook, livelink

I'm trying to get the Outlook ID of a Livelink folder within my VBA project (the default VbaProject.otm). It would allow me to quickly move mails from Outlook to Livelink. I already have the Livelink folder ID but I know that Outlook has its own.

I can get the Livelink StoreID with the following:

```
storeID = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("LiveLink").storeID
```

Now, I have no idea how I could get the Outlook ID. Here is one example of what it looks like:

```
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
```

Anyone has an idea?
Thank you.

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Outlook Spy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) or [MFCMapi](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/). The ID is probably contained as a MIME property you can access via [`Folder.PropertyAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libRary/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.propertyaccessor). See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8041496/175679).

```vb
 Dim liveLinkFolder as Outlook.Folder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("LiveLink")
 Dim id as String = liveLinkFolder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("LiveLink ID").ToString()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. For some reason, I get an error saying that Outlook.Folder is an unknown type. I changed it to Outlook.Folders, which works but ID is null. I've tried changing "Livelink ID" to an actual ID, not sure what I have to change there to get it working. I have the full path in a string and the Livelink ID and a string too, and that's all I got actually to get that Outlook ID.

Comment: You need to use a tool (*Outlook Spy or MFCMAPI*) to figure out the actual property name - I don't have LiveLink, so I can't tell you the property name. I just gave you an example on how to access MIME folder properties.

Comment: I don't have admin privileges even for developement, but I will see what I can do.

Comment: You will need to install one of these tools to inspect the MIME properties and their values.

Comment: Well, managed to install Outlook Spy. I read the other post, forX is actually one of the former employee of the same enterprise I'm actually working for.

What he was trying to do last year with this post was just to get the Livelink ID (the ID in Livelink, not the one that Outlook assigns to each of his folders, Livelink or not). That's not exactly the same thing.

Somehow, the Livelink ID can be found with the following:

`.fields("urn:x-opentext-com:ll:properties:nodeid").value`

Comment: With Outlook Spy, when I select a Livelink folder, then click on the Folder button, I can see MAPIFolder with some properties. One of the properties is EntryID. This looks like the exact right ID I need. Now, is there a way with Outlook Spy to see how we can access it with VBA?